# .htaccess как редиректить 301 все страницы на новый домен если пути одинаковые

Tags: php, .htaccess

У меня есть старый сайт, я хочу с него редиректить на новый, домены разные пути одинаковые, как это сделать, чтобы не прописывать для каждого, подскажите как реализовать через .htaccess?

Пример: olddomean/page.html -> newdomean/page.html

WWW не нужен

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://newdomean/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: @splash58 `L` можно уже не ставить

Comment: @teran я отстал ? :) почитаю

Comment: @splash58 редирект-то внешний, от L толку ноль, он ведь используется для прерывания цикла перенаправлений внутри текущего запроса.

Comment: @teran Спасибо! точно

Comment: Подскажите, не работает .htaccess, в конфиге стоит Alloverride none, хочу поставить all, но сервер выдает 1001 при записи, тп говорит сменить этот пункт через сам файл .htaccess но как это сделать?